# How do I start atom from command line in windows

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am using script package in atom editor to run python.
Everytime I try to run a program it asks "*Did you start atom from command line?"*

How to perform it from a novice's view

Answer (score 2):

Use 'atom' command to start atom from command line.

In the case if it doesn't work, add the atom root/bin directory to the Environment Path.

https://atom.io/docs/latest/getting-started-atom-basics

Comment: Whenever I start python from command line in atom it says that "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. "

Comment: Please add python to the environment. http://pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/